# How to disable shortcut for Spotlight Search programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, nsuserdefaults

I successfully changed the defaults settings for spotlight search via setting 'enabled' to NO using NSUserDefaults, but I need to restart my machine in order to implement the change, I guess there is some process that needs to be restarted. I tried looking through Activity Monitor to identify the process, but it's some minor process and can't absolutely find it. Please help, new to MacOS Development.

````
NSMutableDictionary* spotlightSearchPreferences = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForDefaultsDomain:@"com.apple.symbolichotkeys" key:@"AppleSymbolicHotKeys"] mutableCopy];
 
NSMutableDictionary* spotlightSearchEnabled = [[spotlightSearchPreferences valueForKey:@"64"] mutableCopy];
 
[spotlightSearchEnabled setValue:@NO forKey:@"enabled"];
 
[spotlightSearchPreferences setValue:spotlightSearchEnabled forKey:@"64"];
 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:spotlightSearchPreferences forKey:@"AppleSymbolicHotKeys" forDefaultsDomain:@"com.apple.symbolichotkeys"];```
````